# Operator precedence in C

Tags: c, expression

What happens in C prog while executing the following expression:
x = 4 + 2 % - 8 ;
The answer it outputs is 6,but I didn't get how this snippet is actually executed?

Comment: `%-8` would be invalid if `-` was the subtraction operator.

Comment: Formally speaking, the evaluation of the whole `x = 4 + 2 % - 8` expression conceptually includes conversion of the RHS to the type of `x`. You did not provide us with the type of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case - is the unary negation operator (not subtraction) and it binds tightly to the 8 literal as it has a very high precedence. Note that formally there are no such things as negative literals in c.

So, the modulus term is evaluated as 2 % (-8). The modulus operator has the same precedence as multiplication and division.

Answer (score 2):

The language does not define how it is *executed* since the expression is not sufficiently sequenced to force a specific execution schedule (order of evaluation).

All we can potentially tell you is what it *evaluates to*. Since you did not provide us with the exact type of `x`, it is not really possible to tell what the whole expression evaluates to. For this reason I will restrict consideration to the `4 + 2 % -8` subexpression.

This subexpression is grouped as

```
4 + (2 % (-8))
```

Since `2 / (-8)` is `0` in modern C, `2 % (-8)` is `2`. So the above subexpression evaluates to `6`.

P.S. Note that in C89/90 `2 / (-8)` could legally evaluate to `-1` with `2 % (-8)` evaluating to `-6`. The whole thing would evaluate to `-2`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression give precedence to `%` first so it evaluates `(2 % -8) = 2` and then add `4` to it. So ans is `4 + 2 = 6`.

[Here is quick reference for you](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The unary `-` operator has the highest precedence here.

The `%` operator has precedence equal to that of the `/` and `*` operators, which is therefore higher than that of the `+` operator.

Bottom line, `4 + 2 % -8` is equivalent to `4 + (2% (-8))`.